# Como ajustar nivel de uma barra com listas dupla

Tags: css

Oi criei 2 listas dentro de uma navbar, porém a lista esquerda ta em cima e a direita em baixo, queria que elas ficassem no mesmo nível,

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav.top{
    width: 100%;
   background: crimson;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
}
.esquerda{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.direita{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
   
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(6){
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
ul.esquerda li:nth-child(2){
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
nav ul li i{
    margin: 0 15px;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a{
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    background: #fff;
    
}

@media (max-width:800px){
    .esquerda{
        display: none;
    }
    .direita{
        display: none;
    }
    nav.top{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
 
        <nav class="top">
            <ul class="esquerda">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="direita">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Portfolio</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>
                
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Portfolio</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <h1>TEXTO</h1>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode usar `flex` na `Nav` e usar a propriedade `justify-content: space-between;` para colocar um `UL` de um lado e a outra `UL` do outro

Aqui não vai ficar bom, **mas teste em Página Toda que vc vai ver como fica**, e depois com um `@media` vc trata a responsividade

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: crimson;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.esquerda {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.direita {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 15px;

}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(6) {
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}

ul.esquerda li:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li i {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #fff;

}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .esquerda {
    display: none;
  }

  .direita {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.top {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
  <ul class="esquerda">
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="direita">
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Portfolio</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>

    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>About</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Portfolio</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h1>TEXTO</h1>
```

Comment: Valeu Hugo to iniciando em flexbox, obg fico otmo aqui, abraços desde o do grupo CSS Br.

Comment: @Jslevel isso ai estude bastante Flex, ele ajuda muito a construir layouts! Tmj 